# Come traduciamo in italiano "affordance"?

Tags: translation, neologism

Mi riferisco al significato della parola che viene spiegato [in questa domanda](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128479/what-are-affordances-in-game-design)

Esiste una parola (o un modo di dire o una parola equivalente) specifica che si riferisce al fatto che certe azioni sono percepite come possibili (a causa ad esempio della particolare forma o configurazione dell'ambiente)?

**Il manico di una tazza *suggerisce* che questa possa essere afferrata**, ma "suggerisce" è una parola molto generica.

I buchi nelle prese elettriche suggeriscono ai bambini che sia possibile infilarci le dita (e restare fulminati).

EDIT:

La parola che cercavo non esiste in senso e va coniata, grazie alla risposta di DaG. La soluzione sembra essere una di queste due:

- **Affordanza:** in pratica è la parola stessa ma *italianizzata*
- **Permettenza:** è una parola forse corretta, ma che ho già sentito utilizzare, mi sembra in elettrotecnica per cui alla fine  forse è meglio la prima.

Comment: Per la forma verbale io userei *fare sì che* (e.g. *Il manico di una tazza fa sì che essa possa essere afferrata*), ma non ho idee riguardo al sostantivo.

Comment: Ho provato a investigare un po l'argomento "ergonomia" senza trovare alcunché.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ho trovato il termine affordance non tradotto in testi in italiano sull'usabilità delle interfacce uomo-macchina; penso che in alcuni contesti si possa tradurre con suggerimento, indicazione o invito. "A mouse gives you the affordance of moving and clicking." "Un mouse ti dà il suggerimento di muovere e cliccare."

Comment: Grazie @Charo . Alla fine mi sa che è meglio italianizzare il termine (esattamente come è successo per "implementare").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come è stato ricordato, il termine inglese è piuttosto recente: risale al 1966, coniato da J.J. Gibson, e l'English Oxford Dictionary riporta quella che presumibilmente è la prima frase in cui compare (non considerando un diverso e più antico uso locale della parola):

> When the constant properties of constant objects are perceived (the shape, size, color..[etc.]), the observer can go on to detect their *affordances*. I have coined this word as a substitute for *values*, a term which carries an old burden of philosophical meaning. I mean simply what things furnish, for good or ill. (J. J. Gibson, *Senses considered as Perceptual Systems*, xiii. 285)

«Quando vengono percepite le proprietà costanti di oggetti costanti (la forma, le dimensioni, il colore [etc.]), l'osservatore può procedere a rilevarne le [*affordances*]. Ho coniato questa parola come sostituto per *valori*, un termine che si porta dietro un vecchio fardello di significati filosofici. Intendo semplicemente ciò che le cose forniscono, nel bene e nel male.» (Traduzione di servizio mia, e sono conscio della precarietà di quel “forniscono”.)

Essendo un neologismo anche per l'inglese, ci sono in italiano tre possibilità: 1) prendere di peso la parola inglese; 2) coniare un neologismo italiano; 3) risemantizzare una parola esistente italiana.

1) Il prestito letterale attualmente è forse la soluzione più diffusa in vari ambiti, soprattutto scientifici e tecnici, da “computer” a “cupping”, ma personalmente non incoraggerei questa tendenza, sia perché non ne ha bisogno, sia perché si porta dietro il problema di introdurre termini spesso mal usati, mal pronunciati, di cui a volte non si sa formare il plurale e così via.

2) Il meccanismo classico si limiterebbe semplicemente a adattare alla fonetica e alla grammatica italiane il termine straniero: **affordanza**, così come avvenne in passato per innumerevoli parole entrate in italiano (fra cui viene spesso esemplificata la *beef-steak* che divenne bistecca). Oppure, in una sorta di calco, si potrebbe coniare **permettenza**, ovviamente spiegando di che si tratta quando si introduce il termine (ma anche l'autore anglofono lo fa); può suonare strano, ma dopo tutto è coerente con “urgenza”, “partenza”, “continenza”, “resistenza” etc.

3) L'altro meccanismo che le lingue usano spesso per esprimere nuovi concetti è la risemantizzazione di termini esistenti, cioè prendere una parola e assegnarle un nuovo significato in aggiunta al preesistente. Il senso base di “applicazione” è “atto o effetto dell'applicare” (un cerotto, l'intonaco, una guarnizione, o figuratamente una legge, una regola e così via); nel moderno linguaggio informatico si riferisce invece a un certo tipo di programma; e lo stesso un “lettore” di dischi o file, la “scansione” di un'immagine etc. Anche questo fenomeno si verifica da sempre: pensiamo solo all'“albero” con le foglie, poi a quello della nave e infine a quello del motore dell'automobile.
Quale termine risemantizzare qui lo può decidere meglio chi è più addentro all'argomento, ma Gibson stesso ci suggerisce, anche se per fare una distinzione, **valore**; oppure, come già proposto, **predisposizione**.
La mia proposta principale è però **invito**, che ha già anche il senso di «Qualsiasi accorgimento o artificio costruttivo atto a facilitare l’avvio o l’ingresso; per es., in una scala, il primo gradino, o la serie dei primi gradini, che sporge dagli altri e dalla ringhiera, costituendo quasi un invito a salire; nella viabilità stradale, l’imbocco di un passaggio, di un passo carrabile o anche di una via perpendicolare all’asse della strada principale, che si presenti svasato in modo da facilitare la svolta e l’ingresso di veicoli» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/invito2/), 5).

Comment: Direi allora che il termine che cerco è affordanza, permettenza non lo userei perchè è già usato in elettro-tecnica (l'inverso della resistenza è la permettenza o comunque una parola troppo simile che può essere confusa con permettenza, invece affordanza permetterebbe anche una traduzione più facile avendo l'equivalente inglese).. Grazie! è la risposta che cercavo

Comment: Il termine permettenza o permettanza è stato usato in passato come sinonimo di capacità elettrica in testi di fisica ed elettrotecnica, dunque a mio avviso non è molto adatto come neologismo. L'inverso della resistenza invece dovrebbe essere la conduttanza.

Answer (score 3):

Il termine *affordance* è stato introdotto dallo psicologo James Gibson e rientra nella categoria dei forestierismi di necessità, cioè quelle parole che esprimono concetti che non hanno una controparte nel lessico italiano e a mio avviso non è mai stato tradotto con un neologismo italiano. L'italiano rispetto ad altre lingue (e.g. spagnolo) è abbastanza aperto verso l'adozione di termini provenienti da altre lingue.

Comunque io credo che concetto che si avvicina di più sia quello di predisposizione, o alle volte intuitività.

Answer (score 0):

Parlo da madrelingua italiano; equivalente ad "affordance" c'è soltanto "fa sì" e "permette - (e tutti i suoi sinonimi)" (come qualcun'altro ha anche detto); **Il manico di una tazza** *permette* **che questa possa essere afferrata** (**autorizza; fa sì**). Il termine "affordance" non è un vero e proprio "termine" in italiano, come per il resto altre moltissime parole in altre lingue non hanno una vera e propria "traduzione" in italiano, ma possiamo comunque prendere "spunto - riferimento" da quella parola e la sua definizione nella lingua stessa per comprendere - afferrare "correttamente" il concetto di quella parola. Saluti! :).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!